# NRPE: What's the difference between `only_from` directive and `allowed_hosts` and which one is preferred by NRPE?

Tags: nrpe, xinetd

I see two different places where I can configure which Nagios server my NRPE clients will speak with.

The first one, while configuring NRPE to run under xinetd:

```
only_from       = 127.0.0.1 mon1.company.com
```

The second one, in the `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` file:

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,mon1.company.com
```

My question is:

1. Incase both are configured (`nrpe.cfg` and `xinetd/nrpe`) - Which configuration is stronger? Meaning, which one will override the other?
2. If they do not override each other, should they both be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you configure both (and really use NRPE from `xinetd`), the  `xinetd` configuration is stronger in the sense that a NRPE process will never be spawned if the originating host didn't match, so the configuration you do in the NRPE config fill will never be evaluated.
2. I don't see a reason to do this. It might be a very little bit stronger, but you also increase the chance for misconfigurations. However, you have to be careful if you decide to drop `xinetd` in favor of a daemon mode for NRPE.

Comment: I found old servers in my company which both directives are configrued but NRPE is not responding there from the Nagios server, so i thought it could be problematic and worth a question.. thanks.